# Android studio isn't working properly

Tags: android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio bundle v2.3.3 and in the Gradle console, I'm getting this error:

> Failed to resolve: javax.annotation-api:1.2

At the top of the Android Studio, everything is underlined in red which includes src, main, java, com, example, and main activity.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your computer is connected to the Internet or not. If yes, then I would suggest you to install all the sdk tools and the sdk platforms(at least the ones you're gonna use for the app) if you haven't already.

Comment: I dont get it.Its a bundle contains both sdk tools and android studio ..isnt that true?

Comment: I need help on this guys please

Comment: No, it doesn't contain all the sdk tools it needs for the layouting if xml files and other stuff. Go to Tools->Android->SDK_Manager and then look for the updates.Click the show package details and it will show the details of the tools installed and which are not. (PS. - you need internet connectivity)

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? And is everything installed? for example- SDK build tools version 23.0.1 to 26.0.0

Comment: Yes everything is installed

Comment: try refreshing your project and then clean project.

Comment: is your computer connected through a proxy server?

Comment: post your gradle build content

Comment: Thank you very very much bro ..all i needed was an internet connection

Comment: I told you it need internet. :)

Comment: Also I would recommend you to go to settings and select work offline on Gradle settings to make the Android studio work faster. I would appreciate it if you will accept the answer. :)

Comment: @Chanchrik would be nice for other readers if you'd also update your answer about being connected to the internet.